# spin.js starts but doesnt stop

Tags: javascript

How can I stop the spin? Something strange happens. Here is the code that doesn't work:

```
 <body>
<div id="spin">
</div>
<button type="submit" onclick="spin_stop();" id="stop">Stop</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="spin_start();" id="start">Start</button></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var target = document.getElementById('spin');
    function spin_stop()      {
        spinner.stop();  
    }
    function spin_start()     {
        var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
        spinner.spin(target);  
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which spin.js is this? jquery? custom?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are defining spinner in the function scope of spin_start(), the spinner object in spin_stop is undefined. If you declare spinner where you declare target, that variable will be accessible to both functions.

Comment: @user2047861 if my answer is correct, please mark it is as the correct answer. thank you